# Firebase API Key Application Restriction Problem

Tags: firebase, vue.js, api-key

I received an alarming email from Google a couple of days ago stating that:

> [Action Required] Firebase services for your application are malfunctioning due to Application restrictions

I have a Vue based website that uses Firebase for Authorization of users and storing files they are uploading. When I configured the API key that I set up, I restricted this key on the application level, to only work from the address of my website.

**I did not impose any API restrictions - Under API Restrictions the radio button with Don't Restrict Key is marked**

Having said that, when I try to use my website, I get the following error:

> [403] Requests from referer [WEBSITE] are blocked.

The email I got from Google stated that:

```
Firebase SDK updates on February 27, 2020 (Android) and January 14, 2020 (iOS) replaced the Firebase Instance ID service with a dependency on the Firebase Installations API.

As a result, Firebase services like Firebase Cloud Messaging will malfunction for users who installed your app after it was released with updated Firebase SDKs. Additionally, repeated failing requests to Firebase may slow down the end-user experience of your app.

Application restrictions you have applied to the API key used by your Firebase application need to be updated to allow your application to use the API key.
```

Inside this mail, there were the following instructions:

- Open the Google Cloud Platform Console.
- Choose the project you use for your application(s).  Open APIs &
  Services and select Credentials.
- Click Edit API key  for the API key in question.
- Scroll down to the Application restrictions section.
- Change the radio button to None, and click Save, or add your
  application to the list of allowed    Android apps, iOS apps, or HTTP
  referrers, respectively.
- ***If the radio button already shows None you may be looking at the

  wrong API key.***
- You can check which API key is used for the Firebase Installations
  API by looking at the service usage page for your project.

Since I do not have any API restrictions and there is also no other API key that I have, I don't understand how to solve this situation.

One option that works is having no application restrictions, but I don't think that is the correct solution.

I also tried changing the API Restrictions to allow only the services from Firebase that I am using, but that did not fix the problem.

Any help or direction to a solution, will be appreciated.